WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 126...Selenium Java
I'm new to Selenium, here is the code I am trying to do
Google Chrome Opens, Clicks on Autocomplete, but can't fill the form!?
here is the error I am getting, it might be related to the google chrome version.
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class SeleniumBasics {
    
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {  
    
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();  
    driver.get("https://formy-project.herokuapp.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize(); 
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-lg' and text()='Autocomplete']")).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-lg' and text()='Autocomplete']"))).click();        
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("autocomplete"))).sendKeys("1555 Park Blvd, Palo Alto, CA");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    
}  

}
here is the error message ...please any help is much appreciated...Thank you
juin 28, 2024 12:35:09 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 126
juin 28, 2024 12:35:09 P.M. org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$5
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 126.0.6478.115. You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.16.1` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //a[@class='btn btn-lg' and text()='Autocomplete'] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:229)
    at SeleniumBasics.main(SeleniumBasics.java:18)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=126.0.6478.115)
Build info: version: '4.16.1', revision: '9b4c83354e'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '22'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [5944275f9cbce6396f8f664983b0bbe8, findElement {using=xpath, value=//a[@class='btn btn-lg' and text()='Autocomplete']}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 126.0.6478.115, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 126.0.6478.126 (d36ace6122e..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Kamilia\AppData\Lo...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:56029}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:56029/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 126.0.6478.115, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 5944275f9cbce6396f8f664983b0bbe8
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:133)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:52)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:191)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:200)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:175)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:523)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation$ElementFinder$2.findElement(ElementLocation.java:165)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ElementLocation.findElement(ElementLocation.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:354)


As far as CDP warning is concerned you can find the answer for a similar problem over here. Coming to your error, it is because you are waiting for the Autocomplete button element after clicking on it (Autocomplete button would be vanished once you click on it as the application will move to the next page where AutoComplete button is not present). So you can change the code below
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://formy-project.herokuapp.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-lg' and text()='Autocomplete']")).click();//you can comment this line because the below line is doing the same after waiting for the elment to be clickable
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='btn btn-lg' and text()='Autocomplete']"))).click();
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("autocomplete"))).sendKeys("1555 Park Blvd, Palo Alto, CA");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

